# How do I get user’s IP address while staying approved for Sandbox mode in MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, appstore-sandbox

I’m building an app that requires IP knowledge and I thought you had to turn sandbox off but I noticed an app called [ipman](https://ipman.io/) does this and is in the MacOS App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea offhand if there is a sandbox friendly API, but you could load a dynamic web page from your server which returns the IP address of the requester, or parse the output from one of the many sites that offer the service - search "what's my IP". HTH